# how to bind a non-boolean property to a boolean property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, data-binding

I am designing GUI for my project.
What I need to do is changing the color of a label depending on a boolean in a binding source. But the problem is that I need to assign a Color to the label wheres binding source doesn't have this(I don't want a Color property in binding source).

How can I handle to make label red when bool is true otherwise black?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @Patrick It is WinForms.

Comment: Use a view model that changes the color when the boolean value changes.

Comment: @GertArnold I would suggest exactly what you suggest, but isn't it precisely what bfaskiplar asked to avoid ("I don't want a Color property in binding source")?

Comment: @phoog True, but I think that is because he hasn't got a view model, otherwise the problem would not even exist in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cannot bind them directly, you have to create an extra property on either side. Either you add a Color property in the (business) object (which you said you didn't want), so that leaves adding a property on the form/control which you bind to the property on your (business) object.

UPDATE

If you want to add a property to the form to which you can bind, add the following.

```
public bool MyPropertyToBindTo {
    get { return _myLabel.Color == Color.Red; }
    set { _myLabel.Color = value ? Color.Red : Color.Black; }
}
```

Now you can bind the business-object-property to this property, and it should work.

Comment: I didn't get how it will work If I add a Color property on the form. I suppose you meant a new Boolean property will be bound to bool in business object. But then, how come it is possible to bind the Color of the label to this boolean. I know I can use a simple if-statement but I want to do this job only once in initialization stage. Unless I inspect if bool is changed or not manually in a loop all the time , It will not work. Because those lines where I check if bool variable is changed will never be executed again.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a Converter for this. (I've copied/ updated this code from several sources, please excuse some syntactic errors.)

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color labelColor;
        // Implement your conversion code here ...

        return labelColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // As far as I understood your question you
        // will not need to convert back.
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Then you need to define it in the XAML of your `UserControl` or `Window` in the `Resources` part (converter is the namespace). (In this example, `converter` maps to the namespace in which `BoolToColorConverter` is defined.)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <converter:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="boolToColor" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

After that you can finally use it in your XAML for this binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=YourBoundProperty, Converter={StaticResource boolToColor}}" />
```

Comment: Ah, never mind. In the meantime the question was updated stating that WinForms is used. Just ignore me.

Comment: OP indicated she/he's using WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wpf you can use Converter

Link about color and value : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/value-converter-in-wpf-part-i/

Comment: OP indicated she/he's using WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't bind the boolean property to the control, override the `DataBinding` event, and in that event handler set the `Color` of your `Label` based on the boolean variable.  The `DataBinding` event exists (at least partially) for you to place databinding logic that is too complicated for traditional data binding.